# Capturing multiple optional groups in a regex both repeating and non repeating

Tags: python, regex

I have to match an expression similar to these

> `STAR 13`
>
> `STAR 13, 23`
>
> `STAR 1, 2 and 3 and STAR 1`

But only capture the digits.
The number of digits is unspecified.

I've tried with `STAR(?:\s*(?:,|and)\s*(#\d+))+`
But it doesn't seem to capture the terms exactly.
No other dependencies could be added. Just the `re` module only.

The problem is a much larger one where `STAR` is another regular expression which has already been solved. Please don't bother about it and just consider it as a letter combination. Just include the letters `STAR` in regular expressions.

Comment: Does `STAR` matter at all?

Comment: If you want to validate and get submatches (captures) at the same time with 1 regex, consider using PyPi regex module. However, your requirements are not quite clear.

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: Please, provide the script you've tried.

Comment: read [ask] question on stackoverflow.

Comment: It does matter to me. I want it to match the entirety of the expression. But capture only the numbers.

Comment: Stop rating the question and try to give an answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of the digit `r'[0-9]+'` to specifie 1 digit or more. And to capture all number, you can use : `r'(\d+)'`

Do it with one regex:

```
re.findall("STAR ([0-9]+),? ?([0-9]+)? ?a?n?d? ?([0-9]+)?",a)
```

> [('13', '', '')]
>
> [('13', '23', '')]
>
> [('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '', '')]

May be esaier and cleaner resultut with two step, first you need to have variable in a list like that:

> tab = ["STAR 13","STAR 13, 23","STAR 1, 2 and 3 and STAR 1"]

```
list = filter(lambda x: re.match("^STAR",x),tab)
list_star = filter(lambda x: re.match("^STAR",x),tab)
for i in list_star:
    re.findall(r'\d+', i)
```

> ['13']
>
> ['13', '23']
>
> ['1', '2', '3', '1']

You just need to put it in a new list after that `my_digit += re.findall(r'\d+', i)`

**In 1 line:**

```
import functools
tab = ["STAR 13","STAR 13, 23","STAR 1, 2 and 3 and STAR 1"]
digit=functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+re.findall("\d+",y),filter(lambda x: re.match("^STAR ",x),tab),[])
```

> ['13', '13', '23', '1', '2', '3', '1']

Comment: But that won't match the entire expression. I want it to match the entire expression but capture only the digits.

Comment: See the edit below and it's don't what you want write the exactly resultat you need.

Comment: That's not what I've asked for. The result should be `['13', '23']` for the expression you provided. But it doesn't match the entire string. I want it to match the entire string but only capture the specified groups.

Comment: re.findall("STAR ([0-9]+),?( [0-9]+)??",message) is this in the good way i just don't catch the "3" in the third expression. I see that tomorrow but you catch yours elements in a tuple in a list. May be it's better do to that in two steps for a simple use after.

Comment: You have your answer just above.